# View Windows 8 File History deltas

Tags: windows-8, history, windows-backup

**Summary**: the regular Windows File History viewer shows the user what files will be restored at a given date. Instead, I would like to see what's changed between any 2 restore dates. Preferably recursively over the folder structure.

**Detail**: I had a hard disk go bad. After re-installing Windows 8, I have managed to restore most of my files. However, I notice a few are missing from the most recent File History restore. The missing files were not manually deleted. I suspect that as the original hard disk progressively degraded, File History had to skip files and thus considered them deleted. If I scroll back in time, I can see the files at earlier File History dates. However, it's impractical to do this for thousands of folders. But if I could see the deltas/change sets between dates, I could quickly find which files File History considers deleted & manually restore them.

Comment: This will be an interesting answer. This is a new feature and Google will have limited info.